# Dialog - Continue in background

Tags: background-process, dialog

I installed this program:

http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html

Now I want to use this dialog:

http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog-figures.html#demo_gauge

```
dialog --gauge 'Checking permissions' 20 60
```

It works fine, but the problem is that the bash script does not continue until this dialog has been closed (CTRL + C).

But I want that my shell script continues, and I show the status with the dialog.

Is this possible?

#### EDIT #1

```
status="Initializing"    
(echo 1
 sleep 1
 status="Loading"
 echo 30
 sleep 1
 echo 90
 sleep 1
 echo 100
) | dialog --gauge $status 10 40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to feed the percentages to the gauge via standard input. Try this to see how it works:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100); do echo $i; sleep 0.1; done | \
  dialog --gauge "Example" 10 50
```

So, in your case, just do your work in a subshell, outputting a percentage number every now and then, and pipe it to `dialog`. Something like this:

```
(echo 1
 sleep 1
 echo 30
 sleep 1
 echo 90
 sleep 1
 echo 100
) | dialog --gauge "Working hard..." 10 40
```

(where every `sleep 1` represents some real work, of course...).

**EDIT:** Changing the text

To change the text, you output `XXX`, a number, then the new text, then `XXX` again. Example:

```
(echo 30
 sleep 1
 echo XXX; echo 60; echo "New text"; echo XXX
 sleep 1
 echo 100
) | dialog --gauge "Working hard..." 10 40
```

You need to read `dialog`'s manual page; everything is explained there.

Comment: How can i change the text then? I have edited the question with a example which does not work.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Michael I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry that i did not found that myself, but the doc is so huge, any english is not my native language. I really appreciate your help.